# How to know how much fuel is left when the light turns on

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-tank

In general, where can one find information about the quantity of fuel that is left in the vehicle's tank when the warning light turns on?

More specifically, in a Suzuki Swift GLX (auto) 2010 model?

Comment: The reserve is usually 2 gallons, but due to car tilt and the way that the fuel pump is situated in the tank, the actual usable amount of reserve fuel will be somewhere between 1 and 2 gallons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look up in your owner's manual how capacity your fuel tank has.  Next time you fuel up, take note of the difference.  In my car it's roughly 2 gallons (7.5 liters).  However, realize that modern cars use fuel as a coolant for the fuel pump and running the tank dry often may damage the fuel pump over time.

Answer (score 3):

Look up in your owner's manual and it should tell you how much fuel is left when the light comes on. You can always confirm it by following Parker's answer too.

Comment: None of my cars have ever listed that value in the owner's manual.